# Oracle .NET multiple connections

Tags: c#, linux, vb.net, oracle11g, virtualhost

OK, I have an issue where oracle has not been set up properly on a virtual server and I have no control over the server. I need to delete millions of records from 100+ tables. If I use the same connection it will not push the server to 100% CPU usage. My understanding from the DBA is each connection only utilizes about 1% of the CPU. (Hopefully this makes sense to someone and maybe they can explain this to me) We did some experimenting and when we open multiple instances of sqlplus on the server one for each statement. We are able to push the CPU 100%. I need to duplicate this same scenario using .NET. So I created a program that opens a connection for each statement. Although I see that I have 100+ statements running in Oracle the CPU usage remains at 2%. Am I missing something?  I need an answer in .NET we cannot use partitioning or a DB solution in production we do not have access to the server.

Not exact code:

```
Option max = 100;
Parallel.foreach(tables,blah => {
Using(myContext context new myContext())
{
Context.connection.open();
Context.executestorecommand("delete from table where id in ()");
} 
});
```

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` uses the `ThreadPool` so it will not execute all your statements in parallel.  It will actually execute several groups in parallel where each group is executed in series.  If you want each command executed on its own thread then you'd have to actually create a `Thread` explicitly. Even then though, you're still limited by how many processor cores your machine has as far as how many things can actually be done at exactly the same time.

Comment: I know it doesn't execute all at once it slowly ramps up to 100 threads.  I have a variable that increments and decrements as it executes.  This portion works.  But with supposedly 100 threads going I do not see 100% usage it is as if it is using connection pooling.